# HTML CSS Centering part of text inside a paragraph

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, paragraph

How would I manage to center a part of text which is inside a paragraph?

Example I have a paragraph :

```
<p id="hello">Hello : <span id="love">I love you</span> very much</p>
```

And I want the "I love you" part to be in a new row in center (thats why I tried with span) then rest of the paragraph new row but normal align.

I have tried like this but wont work :

now in css I have :

```
#hello {
    font-size:22px;
    margin: 2em;
}

#love {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you're overcomplicating things.. I'd do this on 3 separate lines with middle line centered

Comment: @kernelpanic Yeah I'm known as the complicator but still I learn more this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#love {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```